# Creating a 2D Array with escaped characters

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, escaping

I have a CSV, let's call it test.csv

```
"country","city","population","remarks"
"germany","munih","1472000","i am a 
line
brake"
"italy","rome","2873000","<>|'"
"spain","madrid","6642000","!"§$%&/("
```

I need a full HTML escaped 2D JS-array without headers and names as like below:

```
"germany","munih","1472000","i am a \nline\nbrake"
```

respectively:

```
var MyVar = [["germany","munih","1472000","i am a \nline\nbrake"],["italy","rome","2873000","&lt;&gt;|&#39;"],["spain","madrid","6642000","!&#167;$%&amp;/(&quot;"]];
```

ConvertTo-Json can escape, but did not find any easy way to produce an 2D-Array without Object Names:

```
Import-Csv ".\test.csv" | ConvertTo-Json -EscapeHandling EscapeHtml
[
  {
    "country": "germany",
    "city": "munih",
    "population": "1472000",
    "remarks": "i am a \r\nline\r\nbrake"
  },
  {
    "country": "italy",
    "city": "rome",
    "population": "2873000",
    "remarks": "\u003c\u003e|\u0027"
  },
  {
    "country": "spain",
    "city": "madrid",
    "population": "6642000",
    "remarks": "!§$%\u0026/(\u0022"
  }
]
```

ConverTo-CSV does a good job, but can't escape:

```
Import-Csv ".\test.csv" | ConvertTo-Csv -UseQuotes Always
"country","city","population","remarks"
"germany","munih","1472000","i am a 
line
brake"
"italy","rome","2873000","<>|'"
"spain","madrid","6642000","!§$%&/("""
```

Following routine works. But I believe, there must be easier way.

```
$t1 = Import-Csv ".\test.csv"

$arr_len = $t1.Count
$obj_len = $t1[0].Psobject.Properties.value.count

$str_builder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr_len; $i++){
    #first outer loop
    if ($i -eq 0){[void]$str_builder.Append('var MyVar = [')}

    for ($j=0; $j -lt $obj_len; $j++){
        #first inner loop
        if ($j -eq 0){[void]$str_builder.Append('[')}
        
        #$t1[$i].Psobject.Properties.Name[$j]
        $each = $t1[$i].Psobject.Properties.Value[$j]
        $each_esc = ([System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlEncode($each)) -replace("`r`n|`r|'n","\n")
        [void]$str_builder.Append('"')
        [void]$str_builder.Append($each_esc)
        [void]$str_builder.Append('"')
        
        #last inner loop
        if ($j -eq ($obj_len-1)){
            if ($i -ne ($arr_len-1)){
                [void]$str_builder.Append('],')
            } else {
                [void]$str_builder.Append(']')
            }
        } else{
            [void]$str_builder.Append(',')
        }
     
    }
    
    #last outer loop
    if ($i -eq ($arr_len-1)){[void]$str_builder.Append('];')}
}

$final = $str_builder.ToString()
[void]$str_builder.Clear()
```

Any hints, ideas? Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the given input it isn't possible to produce the required output.

Youe have to create a nested list first, then the json document.

Try the following:

```
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[psobject]]::new()
foreach($item in $input) {
    $nestedList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

    $itemProps = $item.psobject.properties
    foreach($itemProp in $itemProps) {
        $nestedList.Add($itemProp.Value)
    }
    $list.Add($nestedList)
}

$list | ConvertTo-Json -EscapeHandling EscapeHtml
```

Comment: Never worked before with PS lists. Your generic solution is smart and pretty tidy. Just tried. Looks Awesome. Thank you for sharing this and for giving me the hint, to get closer with lists :)

Comment: You're welcome :). And generic lists are always the best solution, when adding entries on runtime (compared to arrays which are immutable and hit the performance really hard the greater the array gets). Even more, only lists allows you to remove entries.

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify the code like:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

$data   = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\test.csv'

$jsData = foreach ($item in $data) {
 # create an array of quoted encoded strings
 $values = $item.PsObject.Properties.Value | ForEach-Object {
    '"{0}"' -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode(($_ -replace '\r?\n', '\n'))
 }
 # output the encoded strings grouped inside square brackets
 '[{0}]' -f ($values -join ',')
}

# combine the resulting data into a 2D array
$result = 'var MyVar = [{0}];' -f ($jsData -join ',')

$result
```

Output:

```
var MyVar = [["germany","munih","1472000","i am a \nline\nbrake"],["italy","rome","2873000","&lt;&gt;|&#39;"],["spain","madrid","6642000","!&#167;$%&amp;/(&quot;"]];
```

Comment: Hey, thats a really great beautification; thanks for that! Much better than my lame nested for-loops. As well here are tricky new things, which I never saw before. I like this :)
May I ask, what this '[{0}]' -f means respectively, how this kind of loop works? Thx :)

Comment: @TefoD `-f` is PowerShell's format operator. It replaces placeholders in a given string. These placeholders take the form of `{0}`, `{1}` etc. A very neat way of constructing new strings where values need to be inserted.

Comment: @TefoD The loop is itself quite simple. Just a loop through the data an inside another loop to convert the values of each object to js format. Next a couple of `-join` to stich the items together and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: thanks. It's a pitty, that I did not meet Bob before Thats an amazing neat trick. I wrote thousands lines of Code for parsing data, making SQL queries with PS etc.. Its awesome! In other hand, this is not a really favour to me - each time, I gonna touch this code, I will remember you and this format operator, haha 

Comment: @TefoD Thanks. Don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark icon to the left, so others with a similar question can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<#
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      1      0
#>
$fieldsCount = 4
$rawText = @'
"country","city","population","remarks"
"germany","munih","1472000","i am a 
line
brake"
"italy","rome","2873000","<>|'"
"spain","madrid","6642000","!"§$%&/("
'@ 

$rawArray = $rawText.Trim("`"") -split "`r`n" -join "," -split '","' 
$table = $(for ($i = $fieldsCount; $i -lt $rawArray.Count; $i += $fieldsCount){
   [PSCustomObject]@{
      country = $rawArray[$i]
      city = $rawArray[$i+1]
      population = $rawArray[$i+2]
      remarks = $rawArray[$i+3]
   }   
})

$table | ConvertTo-Json

<#
country city   population remarks
------- ----   ---------- -------
germany munih  1472000    i am a ,line,brake
italy   rome   2873000    <>|'
spain   madrid 6642000    !"§$%&/(

 [
  {
    "country": "germany",
    "city": "munih",
    "population": "1472000",
    "remarks": "i am a ,line,brake"
  },
  {
    "country": "italy",
    "city": "rome",
    "population": "2873000",
    "remarks": "<>|'"
  },
  {
    "country": "spain",
    "city": "madrid",
    "population": "6642000",
    "remarks": "!\"§$%&/("
  }
]
#>
```